# Find and replace with Greek letters returns question mark in ArcGis 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, arcgis-10.3, internationalization, find

When I try to replace values in a field with Greek Characters they appear as it should be in attribute, but when I save the edits and re open the attribute I see question mark.

The same thing happens also in Qgis 2.8.1.

I use windows 7 x64 ultimate.

On an other machine which runs windows 8.1 and ArcGis 10.2.1 I see the replaced Greek letters and after reopen the attribute but when I export the attribute in .dbf I don't see anything.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Before going further, try playing around with the solutions posted in these three questions: [Which character encoding is used by the DBF file in shapefiles?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3529/4669), [How to read Greek fonts (ISO-8859-7) in shapefile attributes within QGIS 1.8.0?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/44009/4669) and [Character encoding support in geodatabases and shapefiles](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1461/4669).

Comment: I've checked already these question but I didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reason for this problem and here are some tips.

If you are using Shape file make sure dbf is encoded in proper encoding i.e. UTF-8 or 1253 and you have install the keyboard language support (Greek) to windows as well. You can find these steps here.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12578/add-keyboard-languages-to-xp-vista-and-windows-7/

My personal preference for this kind of stuff is FileGeoDB format. Once everything is OK in FileGeoDB then I export it to shapfile using write encoding setting in the registry.

You must read the following ESRI paper which explains how ArcGIS deal with the DBF encoding.

http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21106

hope that helps.